# Getting the right value_type

Tags: c++, c++11, return-type, decltype, template-argument-deduction

In my class I have a member:

```
std::vector<std::string> memory_;
```

Now I'd like to have a fnc returning what's in the memory's first element but I do not want to specify `std::string` as a return type in case later I decide to use different type for this purpose so I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
typename decltype(memory_)::value_type call_mem()
{
    return memory_[0];
}
```

Any ideas how to specify return type in the most generic way?

Comment: Is `call_mem` a member-function or a free function? If it is a free function, it should probably take `memory_` as parameter. Then you could simply make `call_mem` a function template. If it is a member-function the your class could provide a `typedef` for the type of `memory_`.

Comment: @BjörnPollex hi, thanks, the idea with typedef is nice too. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you use a standard container, that should work, and I think is okay.

Alternatively, since it is a member of a class, then you can use `typedef` and expose the `value_type` as *nested* type of the class:

```
class demo
{
   public:
     typedef std::vector<std::string> container_type;
     typedef container_type::value_type value_type;

     value_type call_mem()
     {
         return *std::begin(memory_); //it is more generic!
     }

   private:        
     container_type memory_;
};
```

Note that `*std::begin(memory_)` is more generic than both `memory_[0]` and `*memory_.begin()` as with it, even arrays would work, but that is less likely to benefit you in real code.

Comment: thanks, never saw this (std::begin(memory_)), like it very much.

Answer (score 1):

You actually just needed to change your formatting slightly, and use the `auto` keyword:

```
auto call_mem() -> decltype(memory_)::value_type
{
    return memory_[0];
}
```

Comment: This is only necessary if the return type somehow depends on function arguments; in this case, the return type is dependent on a class member, so I don't think trailing return type is relevant.

Comment: If I remove the trailing return-type, I get an error from GCC saying `error: 'call_mem' function uses 'auto' type specifier without late return type`

Comment: Bizarre... Can't say I know offhand what the correct behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could just `decltype` the whole expression:

```
decltype(memory_[0]) call_mem()
{
    return memory_[0];
}
```

But ensure that `memory_` is declared before `call_mem`. (and use `std::begin` to generalize to other containers as explained by [@Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164643/getting-the-right-value-type/8164691#8164691).)